# ValueError: Cannot use 'filtered_detections/map/while/strided_slice_1' as input to 'filtered_detections/map/while/ones/packed'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, resnet, retinanet

Training on custom dataset by using Keras retinanet (https://github.com/fizyr/keras-retinanet). while running the retinanet-train command , i got the following error

```
 File "c:\users\samjith.cp\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\control_flow_util.py", line 350, in CheckInputFromValidContext
raise ValueError(error_msg + " See info log for more details.")
ValueError: Cannot use 'filtered_detections/map/while/strided_slice_1' as 
input to 'filtered_detections/map/while/ones/packed' 
because 'filtered_detections/map/while/strided_slice_1' is in a while loop. 
See info log for more details.
```

how to solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

According to [here](https://github.com/fizyr/keras-retinanet/issues/1118#issuecomment-549261561):
`you can use tensorflow 1.14, keras 2.2.5 and keras-retinanet 0.5.1.`.

I can confirm that it fixes the problem.